# Bernoulli equation is the opposite of continuity and pressure formula

Tags: fluid

In fluid physics, continuity says that with a smaller area comes more speed and since P=F/A that means with smaller area comes more pressure therefore with more pressure comes more speed. But Bernoulli says otherwise; with more area comes more pressure therefore less speed

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Note, the pressure and speed increase on one side of a nozzle represent pressure, and speed drop/slow down on the other side. You need to provide examples for comparison,

Comment: 'since P=F/A that means with smaller area comes more pressure'  That assumes that $F$ is constant.  In fact, we know $F$ is _not_ constant, because fluid elements are accelerating in order to have velocity increase with decreasing area, so the forces on the front and back of any given cross-sectional slice of fluid must be unbalanced.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not considering the difference between static pressure ($P=\rho g z$ and the dynamic pressure $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$.

The Bernoulli principle states that the sum of the two (for incompressible flows) remains the same. (I interpret this as another version of the conservation of energy for a incompressible flow).

The result is that when the cross-section reduces the velocity increases. As the velocity increases the dynamic pressure increases. As the dynamic pressure increases the static pressure decreases.

Answer (score 0):

In hydraulics, the pressure is constant everywhere (at a section of a pipe of the pipe if we ignore the depth of the pipe), so your equation $P=F/A$ is not valid.

P is the Pressure on every square unit of area of the pipe, be it the narrow part of the wide part.

But because of the continuity of mass the velocity in the narrow part has to be larger by say, V. This V takes its energy, $\rho\frac{1}{2}V^2$  from the static pressure so the static pressure drops, And it will give its energy back to static pressure of the pipe diameter gets larger.

You can see the conversion between static pressure and velocity at the breakpoint of a large slow wave. the height of the wave crashes down and turn into fast moving skirt of water, providing fast flow for surfers.